# Select options not recognised after adding with Mustache

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I have a select list in a page that is initially as follows:

```
<select id="select-company-type" name="company_type">
    <option value="">Company Type</option>
</select>
```

The options are then repopulated via a Mustache template when another select is changed

```
<script id="companyTypeOptionsTpl" type="text/template">
    <option value="">Company Type</option>
    {{#companies}}
        <option value="{{title}}">{{title}}</option>
    {{/companies}}
</script>
```

This works fine and the new option items appear in the drop down.

However, if I then try and select one of the options programatically with something like:

```
$('#select-company-type').val(selectedOption);
```

where selectedOption contains a string that matches one of the options - it doesn't work.

Also, even if I select an option manually, its value is not passed via GET or POST when the form is submitted.

It's as though the new options are not being recognised although they are visible.

Am I missing a trick here?

Thanks

Comment: Is this `$('#select-company-type').val(selectedOption);` being called after document. ready?  You might also want to do the click event on a parent element like `$('parentelement').on('change','#select-company-name', function() {  // your code here });`  this will work if there are options adding dynamically after page load.

Comment: Yup, it's being called after document.ready, and obviously the form itself is being submitted after the page is ready/loaded so I don't understand why the value of the currently selected option isn't being sent

Comment: What do you get when you add this code `$('#yourForm').on('submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault); alert($('#select-company-type').val()); });`?

Comment: That gives an alert window with a blank message - which suggests it's an empty string. However, if I use:

    alert($('#select-company-type').find(":selected").text());

then I get the text of the selected option, so it looks like the value attribute isn't actually being set by the Mustache template.